# Is there a way to automatically fix all of the possible lint warnings in the whole project in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, lint

Imagine you have a project with **thousands of lint warnings** after you set up analysis_options.yaml file properly. And now you need to fix all of the mess you have. Doing it all by hand can cost you a lot of time, while most of the issues are very simple like "var" instead of "final", double quotes instead of single, etc.

**Is there any way to make Android Studio automatically fix all of the easiest lint warnings** like "Prefer const with constant constructors", etc. in terminal or by running any specific command?

Answer (score 19):

first within the project do : dart fix --dry-run
then after it finish use : dart fix --apply

Comment: I notice some issues are not fixed, eg "Prefer const with constant constructors"... Is there a way to fix those as well?

Comment: where do you enter `dart fix --dry-run` in the GUI?

Comment: @rubo77 in your terminal

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio in the top Menu use

"Analyze" -> "Code Cleanup"

If that doesn't fix it you have to go manually through the result of

"Analyze" -> "inspect code"

See https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint#manuallyRunInspections