# "Use key in widget constructors" warning each time I create a new widget

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I've started getting a warning every time I create a new class.

[image]

> Use key in widget constructors.

> Prefer const with constant constructor.

and so on. Where these errors are coming from and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: In VS Code you can do `Ctrl+.` to 'quick fix' the error and add Key to the class constructor in many cases. That said, i disabled the lint because most of my components are not intended to be re-used and having a key argument is pointless. You can always add one later.

Comment: @rjh Thanks but it wasn't the question about. Even in Android Studio, you can do `control` + `enter` to add that code.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

#### Solution 1:

If you don't want to ignore the warning, just do a `super.key`

```
FooPage({super.key});
```

#### Solution 2:

Open `analysis_options.yaml` file which is located at the root of your project:

```yaml
include: package:flutter_lints/flutter.yaml

# Add these lines
linter:
  rules:
    use_key_in_widget_constructors: false
```

#### Solution 3:

To disable the rule for a specific file, put this line anywhere in your code.

```dart
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors
```

#### Solution 4:

As @Sigiria suggested in the comments, you can run:

```
dart fix --apply
```

#### Solution 5:

Recently Flutter team created a new package [`flutter_lints`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_lints) and it's added to your `analysis_options.yaml` file by default for newly created project.

You can simply remove the following line from your `analysis_options.yaml` file:

```
include: package:flutter_lints/flutter.yaml
```

However, I would suggest you to at least have some rules in it, for example, you can add these rules (from [`pedantic`](https://github.com/google/pedantic/blob/master/lib/analysis_options.1.11.0.yaml)) and remove the one you don't want.

```
linter:
  rules:
    - always_declare_return_types
    - always_require_non_null_named_parameters
    - annotate_overrides
    - avoid_init_to_null
    - avoid_null_checks_in_equality_operators
    - avoid_relative_lib_imports
    - avoid_return_types_on_setters
    - avoid_shadowing_type_parameters
    - avoid_single_cascade_in_expression_statements
    - avoid_types_as_parameter_names
    - await_only_futures
    - camel_case_extensions
    - curly_braces_in_flow_control_structures
    - empty_catches
    - empty_constructor_bodies
    - library_names
    - library_prefixes
    - no_duplicate_case_values
    - null_closures
    - omit_local_variable_types
    - prefer_adjacent_string_concatenation
    - prefer_collection_literals
    - prefer_conditional_assignment
    - prefer_contains
    - prefer_equal_for_default_values
    - prefer_final_fields
    - prefer_for_elements_to_map_fromIterable
    - prefer_generic_function_type_aliases
    - prefer_if_null_operators
    - prefer_inlined_adds
    - prefer_is_empty
    - prefer_is_not_empty
    - prefer_iterable_whereType
    - prefer_single_quotes
    - prefer_spread_collections
    - recursive_getters
    - slash_for_doc_comments
    - sort_child_properties_last
    - type_init_formals
    - unawaited_futures
    - unnecessary_brace_in_string_interps
    - unnecessary_const
    - unnecessary_getters_setters
    - unnecessary_new
    - unnecessary_null_in_if_null_operators
    - unnecessary_this
    - unrelated_type_equality_checks
    - unsafe_html
    - use_full_hex_values_for_flutter_colors
    - use_function_type_syntax_for_parameters
    - use_rethrow_when_possible
    - valid_regexps
```

Comment: Is there any option to solve the warning automatically?

Comment: There's no automatic way of doing it. I recommend you use solution 1.

Comment: It is. You can use: "dart fix --apply". This worked for me

Comment: you have to be careful with that dart command. That generated 20 issues for me

Comment: Also I don't understand many of the changes it did like changing forEach to for

Answer (score 5):

add this in your code right before the @override line

```
const FooPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
```

always add const before the widget command like EdgeInsets, spacer, SizedBox, BorderRadius etc

Answer (score 1):

You can use `prefer_const_constructors : false` in `analysis_options.yaml`

[image]

Comment: What is the difference between 
analyzer:
  errors: and linter.rules