# How do immutable flutter widgets store their mutable states?

Tags: flutter, dart

Warning: `Prefer const with constant constructors`

cause:    - Text("dd")
solution: - const Text("dd")

```
StatefulWidget instances themselves are immutable and store their
mutable state either in separate State objects that are created by the createState 
method, or in objects to which that State subscribes, for example Stream or 
ChangeNotifier objects, to which references are stored in final fields on the 
StatefulWidget itself.
```

Sources:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58136993/462608

**Please give examples to show how do widgets store their mutable states by `createState` method or in objects to which that State subscribes.**

Example:
Which field here is considered `mutable`?

```
class CategoryScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  String productId;

  CategoryScreen(this.productId);

  @override
  CategoryScreenState createState() => CategoryScreenState();
}

class CategoryScreenState extends State<CategoryScreen> {
  List<Item> _data = [];

  CategoryController controller = Get.put(CategoryController());

  setState(() {
     controller.selectedCategoryIndex.value = panelIndex;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you want the fields in your StatefulWidget object to be `final` so instead of `String productId` write `final String productId`. You can reference those fields from the `State` object using the `widget` property, e.g. `widget.productId`.

Fields in the `State` object can be mutable, and in your example both `_data` and `controller` are technically mutable.

Typically you would initialize that data in `initState`, so you might for instance use the `controller` to fill the `_data` list using an API call, then call `setState` to trigger the build of the widget. That's what makes this widget 'Stateful'.

Stateless widget don't hold mutable state (e.g. the `Text` widget has no mutable state, just the text you create it with and it won't change).
Note that Stateless does not mean that a widget cannot change. For example, a stateless widget can listen to a data stream and adjust its representation accordingly - but it won't hold state.